# Spinner с RadioButton

Tags: java, android, button, android-spinner

Хочу самостоятельно создать Spinner в выпадающих пунктах которого есть RadioButton и иметь возможность изменять количество выбираемых RadioButton. Есть работающий вариант с использованием стандартного ArrayAdapter и setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_simplechoice).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner spinner;
String[] data = {"one","two","three","four","five"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setPrompt("ETO ZAGOLOVOK");
    spinner.setSelection(3);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Item " + position + " pressed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Но при передаче методу своего layout активными можно сделать все RadioButton, и я не понимаю как это исправить и добавить возможность выбора нескольких из них, чтобы Spinner не сворачивался при выборе одного. В коде ArrayList вообще не вижу работу с радибаттонами, но при передаче android.R.layout.select_dialog_simplechoice или android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice все работает как надо. Вопрос - как сделать, чтобы переданные в метод setDropDownViewResource кастомные layout содержащие radiobutton работали также как и стандартные

Comment: Идем сюда: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner и видим: Spinners provide a quick way to select one value from a set. Только один вариант. Не пытайтесь впихнуть в него множественный выбор. Лучше сделайте свою реализацию или поищите на просторах интернета библиотеку с тем, что вам нужно

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015686/android-spinner-with-multiple-choice) в ответах есть реализация